# Receive call when app is terminated in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, call

I am new to the swift. I am working on `chat app`.

How receive a call when an app is terminated?
I saw some document. But didn't understand how to use apple VoIP license.

What do i need to do?

Use license? Use `VOIP` service?

and how use `Pushkit`?

How create socket listener service or background app?

Is it possible to run the app by push notification?

Thx.

Comment: There's alot there. Maybe you need to research CallKit (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) and then come back with some specific questions? I'm not sure I can code your whole app here...

Comment: Pushkit - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit, enable VOIP notifications in your App.

Answer (score 0):

To manage inbound/outbound voice calls, see CallKit. Read also this tutorial: [CallKit tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios).
To awake the app when the user receives a message in a chat, you should implement Push Notifications (APN). You have the following tutorial which can help you: [Push notifications tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started)
Then add a library to send the push notifications with message texts. A very good framework is this: **APNS** on GitHub. It's written in Swift 3.0 and it supports some of the latest features.
When someone writes a text on a chat you should push a notification using the ID of the destination device. The recipient will get a notification, and through the notification you can also start the app and open the View Controller with the active chat. You should also use a cloud service (like Google Firebase) to keep a list of the device IDs for all devices registered in your chat app, so that you know exactly which device to "push" when a message is sent. Hope this helps you. iOS is not like Android which has Services, iOS apps cannot run in background with the exception of a few types (GPS, music player and a few others) which must be registered with the system for those purposes.